# Image of $f(x,y) = (y^2, y^4)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to find the image of that function, I can not understand how to find image of multi-variable functions.

Let us say we have the function:
$f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3,  (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,x^2+y^2)$

The image will be: $z = x^2 + y^2$.
But the image of the function I wrote at the post:
$f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2, (x,y) \mapsto (y^2, y^4)$    will be $y = x^2$.

I can not understand how to determine the image, Any tip will be appreciated!!

Comment: The first step would be to recall the definition of the image. The image is a set, not an equation.

Comment: @klirk problem is, at our lecture, the proffesor talked about images in a really basic way. I know image of linear transformation from linear algebra 1 and 2, but in calculus 3, it is a new way of learning, we was shown only basic ones.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer, starting from the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in the first case you could describe it by a system of three equations where $x:=x, y:=y, z:=x^2+y^2$ which can we can use to describe the image. However the image is a set so it is better described as all $(x,y,x^2+y^2) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  Note that image is always a subset of the range so it can't be described by $z=x^2+y^2$ as it's not a full description of a subset. This one is easy because $x:=x, y:=y$ seriously simplifies the problem. It's basically given to you in the question.

Similarly if $x:=y^2$ and $y:=y^4$ then we have $y=(y^2)^2=x^2$. So the image will almost be the set of all $(x,x^2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ because of the $y=x^2$ condition. However because $y^2$ is positive, the image will only contain those $x \geq 0$. Note that just like in the previous problem we end up describing one variable as a combination of the one we fixed, which is $x$ in the case and was $x,y$ in the former. Being able to find such a combination depends heavily on the function as many cases don't allow such simplifications.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
Regarding what you said, being the image subset of range, so does that mean that the graph will not be a paraboloid, but a graph on x,y axis? I can not seem to understand if you mean I have to draw a graph on x,y axis or I can do it x,y,z axis. 
Regarding the second one, got it, thanks :)

Comment: @BenShaines your second example is correct. The image of the first subset is a cone that has a peak at $(0,0,0)$. You can think of the $x^2+y^2$ term as the radius of a circle expanding out from the origin.

The second equation is simply $y=x^2$ which is the parabola that you know. In general for a vector valued function $f(x)$ with $x$ also a vector the graph of that function will be of the form $(x,f(x))$ but drop some brackets. so like $(x,y) \rightarrow (x,y,f(x,y))$ and $x \rightarrow (x,x^2)$ are both graphs of a function, but not these functions because of domain and range.

Comment: Allright, so in the $x^2+y^2$ it should be probably a circle as you said, and the other, got it.
Thanks alot!

Comment: @BenShaines happy to help. Since you seem new to the site you can accept an answer if you feel happy with it. It will be prioritized if other users search for it that way. If you want more answers leave it open to keep attracting attention to the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry! I will do it, didnt notice

Comment: @BenShaines no worries! We're all new once, right?

Comment: Thanks :) (......)

Comment: @BenShaines I made a mistake that the other answer pointed out. I've added the $x \geq 0$ condition meaning it's only half the parabola. This is because $y^2$ will always be positive.

Comment: Yea of course :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$Imf=\{(y^2,y^4):(x,y)\in \mathbb R ^2\}$ **by definition**.
Then $$Imf=\{(y^2,y^4):y\in \mathbb R \}=\{(x,x^2):x\in\mathbb R\}\cap\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x\geq0\}$$

We recognize in the RHS the graph of $\mathbb R \to\mathbb R,x\mapsto x^2$, otherwise written $Imf$ is the right hand side of the parabola.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, regarding the answer. I am trying to think, how you can think of doing $(y^2,y^4) = (x,x^2)$, that is my problem, I dont know how to think like that.

Comment: At first, it's normal: take it easy with a double inclusion.

Comment: I dont know what is double inclusion :(
But I will try to understand, thanks :)

Comment: To prove that $A=B$ you first prove that $A\subset B$ then that $B\subset A$ ("double inclusion")

Comment: Oh sorry, bad english ( saw wrong google translation ). Yea that I know, but I dont know how it relates to here.

Comment: @BenShaines double inclusion is often a great way to prove two sets are equal. The approach I gave is more common in engineering disciplines but double inclusion is a mathematical technique that has applications well beyond multivariable equations. Problems you can often be solved using multiple techniques and approaches so it can be useful to have a second way to look at the problem.

Comment: @CyclotomicField yea but the problem is I dont see how I can do inclusion here, I guess I miss a little of information regarding this.

Comment: @BenShaines it's so trivial that you almost can't find the double inclusion. I'm sure that's why they didn't mention it in their answer.

Comment: well, we did not learn something like that hehe, only in liner algebra and discrete mathematics. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take each problem on a case by case basis.  In your problem you want to know what the set of points $\{(y^2, y^4)| y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ looks like in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  You can see that the $y$-coordinate is the square of the $x$-coordinate. This means that the set of points in question is a subset of the graph of $y = x^2$.  We know what that graph looks like.

In the set of points we are looking at we note that the $x$-coordinate is never negative.  From this it is easy to see that this set of point is the right hand side of the parabola $y = x^2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.
Is there any way I can think of when coming to an exercise like this?
Because with the second case I gave here, why is it $z=x^2+y^2$? I cant think to know how to think that way.
And about the answer you just gave, so if I paint a graph, it will look like a parabola with only the right side? cus when I set points, I really get what you say, only the right side, but I dont know how to think of it...

Comment: To draw the image of the originally stated problem you just draw the right hand side of the graph of the parabola $y=x^2$.  As for the other problem.  You have the set of points $(x, y, x^2+y^2)$.  Note the first two coordinates are free variables and the third depends on the first two.  Thus it's the graph of $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. hmm, the problem is, how do I think like that? about $y=x^2$.
Regarding the second, wait, what? I dont need to draw 3d? paraboloid? since it is $z=x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 0):

The image $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ of a function $f: X\to Y$ is defined as the subset of  $Y$ such that $y \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$ if and only if there exists $x\in X$, such that $f(x) = y$, or short
$$\operatorname{Im}(f) = \{y\in Y~|~ \exists x\in X \text{ such that } f(x)=y \}.$$

In our case, $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ with $f(x,y) = (y^2, y^4)$.

To formally prove what the image is, we first need a candidate, let's call it $A\subset \mathbb R^2$. We see, that for $f(x,y) = (y^2, y^4)$, the second coordinate is the square of the first coordinate. So lets try

$$ A = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 | ~y = x^2 \}$$

We need to show $\operatorname{Im}(f) = A$. Usually, this is done by showing $\operatorname{Im}(f) \subset A$ and $A \subset \operatorname{Im}(f)$, i.e., we need to prove two things.

1. If $(x,y)\in \operatorname{Im}(f)$, i.e., if there exist $x_0, y_0$ such that $(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) = (y_0^2, y_0^4)$, then $(x,y)\in A$, i.e., then $x^2=y$.
2. If $(x,y)$ in $A$, i.e. if $x^2= y$, then $(x,y) \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$, i.e., there is $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb R^2$ such that $(y_0^2, y_0^4) = f(x_0,y_0) = (x,y)$.

But there is a catch, one statement is false, so $A$ is actually not the image. Do you know how to modify $A$ in the right way?

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the help.
I already managed to understand it ,but thanks thought :)
Regarding the double inclusion. a little problem, since we have not learned how to do it with multi-variables